# how to set currency code in square payment gateway? and what types of currency it support.?

Tags: square

i have integrate payment gateway in my web application on PHP and i want to use CAD or GBP for currency so how to use that currency and what types of currency support it.

I have to set as below:

```
$request_body2 = array("amount_money" => array (
                    "amount" => (int)$total_ammount,
                    "currency" => "USD"
                 ));`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all of Square's supported currencies [here](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#type-currency).

In order to charge a card in a specific currency, your location must support that currency. See Square's documentation on [Charge](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-charge) for v2 in the section for `amount_money`.

> The value of currency must match the currency associated with the business that is charging the card.

You can also only create locations for the country with which you had registered your Square account. So if you had registered in the US, you can only create US locations and process `USD` on your Square account.

If you're processing payments on behalf of other Square accounts (using OAuth), then you could process the payment in the currency that matches that Square account's country.